How do I use an $and inside $elemmatch in a MongoDB Query?
I tried to concoct an example of using $and inside $elemMatch in a MongoDB query for my students.  It did not work, and I didn't understand from the error message how I should properly write the query.
Here's a made-up example along the same lines: (we are using pymongo)
student = {
    'name' : 'Gia',
    'grades' : [100.0, 71.5, 83.4, 94.8] 
}
collection.insert_one(student)

student = {
    'name' : 'Arthur',
    'grades' : [91.0, 71.5, 63.4, 94.8] 
}
collection.insert_one(student)

print("Here are all students that got a B grade:")
search_dict = {
    'grades' : { '$elemMatch' :
                  { '$and' :
                    [ { '$gte' : 80.0 },
                      { '$lt' : 90.0 } ]}}
}
results = collection.find(search_dict)
for result in results:
    print(result)

When I run this, I get this error:
pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: unknown top level operator: $gte, full error: {'ok': 0.0, 'errmsg': 'unknown top level operator: $gte', 'code': 2, 'codeName': 'BadValue'}
How can I use $and inside of an $elemMatch?  Or should I be doing something entirely different?

hmm i dont think the $and is needed here https://mongoplayground.net/p/a1S0INNtPhw. from the docs

Thank you!  I'm glad there's another way to do it.  I'm also disappointed because my actual in class failed example was with $or instead of $and.

sorry but i didn't get what scenario you were trying to cover with the $or

When testing with $or, would $elemMatch even be useful?

@cmgchess  my goal was to demonstrate how to use $and and $or deeper in a query.  We had already covered $elemMatch, so I was a bit flustered to see that that didn't work and wanted to know why.  I looked at other answers, but they were mainly using elemMatch on objects instead of arrays, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23726927/or-statement-in-elemmatch

@Joe Not really, because you can just use $in and provide the list of options, but I wanted to show my students $or used deeper inside a query.  I figured there must be someway to write it using both, but perhaps not.

elemMatch has 2 purposes: ensure that the queried field is an array, and ensure that all criteria inside the elemMatch are satisified by a single element of the array.  If it were an array of documents, you would be able to refer to field names and construct a proper $or or $and, for that array of scalar values, you might be able to get the behavior you want with array filters.
